# Laravel 5.4 Pusher Timestamp expired: Given timestamp not within 600s

Tags: laravel, pusher

Timestamp expired: Given timestamp (2018-02-12T01:47:29Z) not within 600s of server time (2018-02-12T02:48:51Z)

noob here need help

Comment: Is this on a local server or hosting server? It is likely that your server time or your computer time is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your server datetime. It have a wrong datetime

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate -u ntp.nasa.gov time-b.nist.gov
```

Comment: Have you fixed  your problem, @Lincoln ?

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vagrant / Homestead your system time can shift and become out of sync when your computer goes to sleep.

```
vagrant ssh
sudo apt install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpd -gq
sudo service ntp start
```

Then

```
  cd /path/to/homestead
  vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
  vagrant halt
  vagrant up
```

I had the same issue and correcting my system time in this manner solved it for me. The discussion here was helpful: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/799